# Can I restore a deleted Svn repository from a local check out?

Tags: svn, restore

I have deleted my main repository on my server accidentally. This is a personal server so it does not affect anyone else. I have a local check out (via svn co) of the files in tact on my desktop. I am wondering if it is possible to reconstruct the Svn server repository from a local check out ?

I am not a pro Svn user so I really do not know the details of svn much, but I know that unlike Git, Svn`s server repo is not same as the a local check out. So it is not as easy as copying it back, at least that is what I assume myself.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best you can do is setup a new repo, delete the .svn directories in your working copy, then import the files into the new repo.  You will need to then go to any existing working copies and switch them to the new repo.  You'll probably need to do a switch --relocate.

Comment: Thanks for your help. How about file revisions?

Comment: In case of svn history is lost. Use git.

Comment: @yaruncan revision history would be gone.

Comment: Thanks @all. I now know one of the shortcomings of Svn. I went for Svn due to the files sizes I have to checkin (over gbs of binary files). I am not sure if Git is an option for me but I will give it a try.

Comment: @yaruncan - for large binary files (which in best case must be excluded from versioning and you'll save only **sources**) Git is shitty choice. Mercurial with langefiles extension **is answer**

Answer (score 1):

First: no backup of SVN-Repo is a pain and should not happen.
But same happened to me. I started to add thousands of files again, file for file, because I don't want to checkin temporary or other no-source-files.

Nearly all history is lost. But **not the last checkin state is lost**!
I managed to get the last checkin state, so the new repo was similar to the old one and I got also the last diff!

This is my recipe with Tortoise:

1. backup your local checkout
2. clean up your local checkout.
3. 1. uncheck: Clean up working copy status

      check:
   2. Delete unversioned
   3. Delete ignored
   4. Revert all
4. create new repo
5. checkout new repo into new empty folder
6. copy the old cleaned copy into new folder
7. add simply all files
8. commit it
9. overwrite your new checkout folder with the backup from 1.

now you've got all files as before, with the last diff and only the files versioned, like before.